# How to change values in the SET Method

Tags: java

I am starting to develop my skills in JAVA, however I have a doubt.
I'm creating an object in JAVA, created the constructor and so on, then, it asks "Change the AGE_RECENT value from 1 to 3", I initially declared this as final because I never thought it would change, so no SET or GET were created. I am wondering how can I change the value from 1 to 3 in the SET Method.
I have this variable

```
private static int AGE_RECENT=1;
```

I did this.

```
   public void setAgeRecent() {
    Vehicle.AGE_RECENT = 3; 
}
```

It works if you run the program, it changes the variable's value, however nothing was declared in that method as every SET method. 
Just wondering how can I do this. If this is correct, good, if not, thanks for helping!

As someone asked, the code.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tp1;

/**
 *
 * @author Nelson
 */
public class Vehicle {

/** Variáveis da classe, têm como função **/
 private String registration;

private int registrationYear;

private double consumption;

private double autonomy;

private int cilinderCapacity;

/**
* Final variables. They are final because they do not suffer any kind of modification during the project.
* YEAR_OMISSION is 2016 because the currect year is 2016. 
* ENVIRONMENTAL_CHARGE_OMISSION is 0.10(10 cents), gave this value because there is nothing to mention the
especific value, hence why I gave 0.10.
* RATING_RECENT = Is a string, just has the text "RECENT" inside.
* RATING_COMTEMPORY - Another string, just with the "Comtempory" text inside.
* RATING_CLASSIC - Yet again another string, with the "Classic" text.
* AGE_RECENT - It is to help to compare if a vehicle is recent or not, it has the value 3.
* AGE_CLASSIC - It is to again help to compare, value is 20.
*/

private static final int YEAR_OMISSION = 2016;
private static final double ENVIRONMENTAL_CHARGE_OMISSION=0.10;
private static final String RATING_RECENT="Recent";
private static final String RATING_CONTEMPORY="Contempory";
private static final String RATING_CLASSIC="Classic";
private static int AGE_RECENT=1;
private static final int AGE_CLASSIC=20;




/**
* Constructor of the object, it has the Registration
     * @param registration
     * @param registrationYear - The year the vehicle was first registered.
     * @param consumption - How many liters the vehicle consumes.
     * @param autonomy - How many KMs a vehicle can go without refuelling.
     * @param cilinderCapacity - How many Cubic Inches the engine has.
*/
 public Vehicle(String registration,int registrationYear, double consumption, double autonomy, int cilinderCapacity) {
 this.registration = registration;
 this.registrationYear = registrationYear;
 this.consumption = consumption;
 this.autonomy = autonomy;
 this.cilinderCapacity = cilinderCapacity;
 }

/**
* Null Constructor, it has no values, they will be attributed in the MAIN Class.
*/

 public Vehicle() {
 this.registration = "";
 this.registrationYear = 0;
 this.consumption = 0;
 this.autonomy = 0;
 this.cilinderCapacity =0;
 this.registrationYear = YEAR_OMISSION;
}
 /**
* Copy Constructor.

 */
public Vehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
 this.registration = vehicle.getRegistration();
 this.registrationYear = vehicle.getRegistrationYear();
 this.consumption = vehicle.getConsumption();
 this.autonomy = vehicle.getAutonomy();
 this.cilinderCapacity = vehicle.getCilinderCapacity();
 }

    public String getRegistration() {
        return registration;
    }

    public int getRegistrationYear() {
        return registrationYear;
    }

    public double getConsumption() {
        return consumption;
    }

    public double getAutonomy() {
        return autonomy;
    }

    public int getCilinderCapacity() {
        return cilinderCapacity;
    }


    public double getYearRecent() {
        return AGE_RECENT;
    }

    public double getAgeRecent(){
        return AGE_RECENT;
    }



    public void setRegistration(String registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
    }

    public void setRegistrationYear(int registrationYear) {
        this.registrationYear = registrationYear;
    }

    public void setConsumption(double consumption) {
        this.consumption = consumption;
    }

    public void setAutonomy(double autonomy) {
        this.autonomy = autonomy;
    }

    public void setCilinderCapacity(int cilinderCapacity) {
        this.cilinderCapacity = cilinderCapacity;
    }

   public void setAgeRecent() {
    Vehicle.AGE_RECENT = 3; 
}



/**
 * Calculate the age of the vehicle to compare in the vehicleRating method
 * @return The year, which is 2016 minus the year the vehicle was first registered.
 */
private int calculateAge(){
    return YEAR_OMISSION-this.registrationYear;

} 

/**
 * Calculate the Circulation Tax.
 * @return Returns the value of the Environmental Charge multiplied by the Cilinder Capacity of the vehicle.
 */
    public double calculateCirculationTax(){

  return ENVIRONMENTAL_CHARGE_OMISSION*cilinderCapacity;

        }





   /**
    * Classify the vehicle based on the age.
    * If the result given by the calculateAge method is minor than the AGE_RECENT variable(3), then it will
    return "Recent"
    * If the result is between Age_RECENT and AGE_CLASSIC(20), then it will say "Contemporary"
    * If none of the IFs apply, it will return "Classic".
   **/
public static String vehicleRating(Vehicle vehicle) {
if(vehicle.calculateAge() < Vehicle.AGE_RECENT) { 
    return  Vehicle.RATING_RECENT; }
else if ((vehicle.calculateAge()>=Vehicle.AGE_RECENT)&&(vehicle.calculateAge()<=Vehicle.AGE_CLASSIC)){
    return Vehicle.RATING_CONTEMPORY;}
else 
 return Vehicle.RATING_CLASSIC;

}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" + "registration=" + registration + ", registrationYear=" + registrationYear + ", consumption=" + consumption + ", autonomy=" + autonomy + ", cilinderCapacity=" + cilinderCapacity + '}';
    }


}
```

Comment: variable is not final, is static, that means it belongs to the class, there is a huge difference between static and final variables.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the rest of your code so we can see what's going on. That property would probably be best suited to be an instance variable and not a class variable.

Comment: I know its not final, it was at the start, but if I wanted to change it, it would be impossible as you are aware, I deleted the FINAL.

Comment: ok, so dont make it static, it should just be "private int AGE_RECENT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setter that takes no arguments is simply a method, not a setter. In order to work as a setter a method must take a parameter that matches the type of the value being set - in your case, that would be `int`:

```
public static void setAgeRecent(int age) {
    AGE_RECENT = age; 
}
```

Note a few things here:

- Since `AGE_RECENT` is `static`, `setAgeRecent` should be `static`
- Since `AGE_RECENT` and `setAgeRecent` are static members of the same class `Vehicle`, you do not need to qualify `AGE_RECENT` with `Vehicle`

Now users of your class would be able to call your static setter as follows:

```
Vehicle.setAgeRecent(3);
```

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. An argument could be made in favor of `static` (i.e. "any vehicle regardless of its model is considered recent") and non-`static` (i.e. "a three-year old Mercedes is recent, while Honda is recent only if it's under a year"). Ultimately it is up to the program designer to decide which approach he is going to take.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yeah, just saw the whole code and it makes somewhat sense now.

Answer (score 0):

A static varible, or class variable, may be used without the need to create an instance of that class. But its value may be changed freely at runtime.

A final variable is not a variable in a true sense, because it's value can't be changed at runtime.

Thus, you may have a set method for a static variable, but never to a final variable.